# Javascript not properly redirecting

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am working in **PHP Codeigniter.**
My page's **current URL** is =>  `http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/merchant/login`
On an event i want to redirect my page to => `http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/category`
I am trying **following code**,

```
window.location = '<?php echo json_encode(base_url("category"));?>';
```

**also tried**

```
=>window.location.href , top.location
```

But it redirects me to,

```
http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/merchant/"http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/category"
```

I've **also tried for debugging** this code,
window.location = "google.com"
but it redirects me to => `http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/merchant/google.com`

Comment: why do you `json_encode` the url before outputting? looks like a quoting error, why are the backticks surrounding the string?

Comment: You need to sepcify http:// inorder to redirect it to external uri

Comment: the json_encode is adding quotes to your string that you are wrapping in quotes. So if you viewed the source of your page, you would see `'"http://website"'`. If you are not outputting json, json_encode is not needed.

Comment: It needs to be an absolute URL, and it needs to be a regular string.  Your first attempt wasn't a regular string, your second attempt wasn't an absolute URL.  They both failed for two different and valid reasons.

Comment: You don't need json_encode.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn but the error is actually that it redirects me to
http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/merchant/"http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/category"

Answer (score 1):

You are using ` characters in your string and I'm not sure why?

Change your redirect to this:

```
window.location = '<?= json_encode(base_url("category)) ?>';
```

In explanation, using

```
<?= value ?>
```

is the shorthand form of

```
<? echo value ?>
```

Comment: , I've written as 
window.location = '<?php echo json_encode(base_url("category"));?>';

Answer (score 0):

You've got extra quotes around the url.  Try this...

```
window.location = '<?php echo json_encode(base_url("category"));?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved : json_encode() puts quotes around string. used following code and everything becomes ok.

```
var url = '<?php echo json_encode(base_url("category"));?>';
url = url.replace(/"/g, "");//to replace quotes with ""
window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:-

```
window.location.href = '<?php echo json_encode(base_url("category"));?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

-- EDIT --
You could use PHP to detect if they or the event is true or equal to something and if it is do

```
header("Location: /hbs/category");
```

That might also be a non-js solution if you could use it in this case..

For example:

```
if (foo()===true){
    header("Location: /hbs/category");
}
```

---

Could try

```
window.location = "http://localhost.hbs.com/hbs/category"
```

Also

```
window.location = "google.com"
```

makes it think it's pointing to something in the folder (ex. hbs/index.html, not a new site.)
You'd want

```
window.location = http://google.com
```